# Firebase FCM get reg_id that caused the NotRegistered error

Tags: android, python, pyfcm

I have this response;

```
{'failure': 1, 'canonical_ids': 0, 'success': 1, 'multicast_id': 01234, 'results': [{u'error': u'NotRegistered'}, {u'message_id': u'0:1475496554732379%48fdacf748fdacf7'}]}
```

Before in GCM I'm able to get which `reg_id` failed, but now in FCM I don't have that information. Is there some way to get specifically which reg_ids failed?

Thanks

Comment: You can print the value in the logcat. This error occurs if your token has changed at the firebase server. Can be due to reinstallation of app

Comment: I just wanna get this value: {"failure": 1}, but which one failure? Did you get it?

Comment: I didn't get it?You want the reg_id for which it failed?right

Comment: yes, If I have 3 regs_id and 2 falied, I wanna know which ones failed.

Comment: I've found the answer in the documentation:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: good for you.. enjoy coding